# SetTime on javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know why the following code is not displaying time. I think it should work by displaying time. Please, I need a help here.

```js
    function startTime() {
      var today = new Date();
      var h = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
      var s = today.getSeconds();
      // add a zero in front of numbers<10
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      document.getElementById(‘txt’).innerHTML = h + ”: ”+m + ”: ”+s;
      t = setTimeout(‘startTime()’, 500);
    }

    function checkTime(i) {
      if (i < 10) {
        i = ”0” + i;
      }
      return i;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body onload=”startTime()”>
  <div id=”txt”></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: start with looking at your developer console. Surely those quotes are going to give you a headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the weird quote marks you're using, `<div id="txt"></div>`.

Comment: Please, what can i do?

Comment: you are using decorative quotes! Use regular quotes

Comment: @O.Brainwave use normal quotes, like `"` not `”`.

Comment: @O.Brainwave that applies to all your code, all the quotes in your code (single and double) aren't valid.

Answer (score 0):

**Console** is your friend.

Error - Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

**Valid code**:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    function startTime() {
      var today = new Date();
      var h = today.getHours();
      var m = today.getMinutes();
      var s = today.getSeconds();
      // add a zero in front of numbers<10
      m = checkTime(m);
      s = checkTime(s);
      document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ':' + m + ':' + s;
      t = setTimeout('startTime()', 500);
    }

    function checkTime(i) {
      if (i < 10) {
        i = '0' + i;
      }
      return i;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload='startTime()'>
  <div id='txt'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotes marks `"` and `”` are different as are `'` and `’`.  You want to use the first one when writing code, the second one happens a lot when things get copy and pasted, and it's invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the following code and try, It will definitely work.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
}
function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
{
i="0" + i;
}
return i;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="startTime()"> <div id="txt"> </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It's because of the **quotation** you have used. You have used **”** but it's supposed to be **"**.

Use some good editor to build the web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Other than what other people have answered, you also have an error here:

```
t = setTimeout('startTime()', 500);
```

Change it to

```
t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
```

So that it will update the time correctly.